# How to resume Android Espresso test after 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have Espresso test have more than 120 test cases but if application crashes 'Instrumentation runs failed due to 'Process crashed.'
The test does not resumes.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found Android Test Orchestrator. It is a tool-supported for AndroidJUnitRunner version 1.0 or higher, which solves two major issue of UI Testing

1. Occasional crashes which stop the entire test suite.
2. Test overlap.

For more details, you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator)